# Application uninstalled but database still available into Mac OS X Device

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sqlite

I am still working on one application with using database. I had made the application successfully and create .app file.

Now whenever I had installed .app file into Mac device, and run this application, database create and working successfully. But while I had uninstalled that application from the Mac device and again install .app file into the same Mac OS X device and run this application, previously created database data loaded.

Query was while I had uninstalled application from device, database not removed from device.

Anyone have an idea? Suggest me.

Comment: *Your* code saves the database somewhere. *You* are the one who's supposed to know where, and then to code something that deletes it when the app is uninstalled...

Comment: @Moritz, I know database path and had delete it manually and try to make this programatically. But still I have a query that which function or a method called while uninstalling application?

Comment: "Method called while uninstalling application" this doesn't store your app data, debug it properly to db location path to know why it is getting stored.

Comment: The app's data is not stored as part of the app, so removing the app doesn't remove the data. There's no programmatic way to handle uninstalling apps in macOS, they're just moved to the Trash. There's no way to automatically remove the associated data along with the app.

Comment: I had solved it with create my database into Application's bundle path. So that it's create it into bundle path while installing and also removed while uninstalling application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the above question solution. I had solved this issue with create application database into application bundle path. So whenever I will install application into device, database will create into bundle path and whenever I will uninstall the application from any device, database will be removed with uninstalling application.

Comment: This is a bad idea. For one thing, you'll run into permissions problems if the user using the app isn't the one that installed it (and hence owns it). If you have multiple users accounts trying to use it, they'll trip over each other. Also, it means you can't code-sign the app, since changes inside the bundle will invalidate the signature (and in some cases this'll prevent it from opening).